# Typescript import class to service class

Tags: typescript

here is my folder structure and i want to import PolicyDetail class to Policy.Service class how can i do that here im tired following code

in my Policy.Service  class :

```
import { PolicyDetail } from '/App/Shared/PolicyDetail';
```

folder structure

```
App
 -- Shared/
         -  PolicyDetail.ts

 --Quote/
        -Services /
                  -- Policy.Service.ts
```

Comment: `import { PolicyDetail } from 'App/Shared/PolicyDetail'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports are always relative to the current file's location. That means you have to specify how to get to PolicyDetail from Policy.Service. It would be something like this.

```
import { PolicyDetail } from '../../Shared/PolicyDetail';
```

Demistification:

1. We start from the location of Policy.Service that being the Service folder.
2. We go to the parent (../) and end up in the Quote folder.
3. From here we go once again to the parent (../) and end up in the App folder.
4. From here we have to go in to the shared folder (Shared/) and specify which  file we want from it (PolicyDetail).

Comment: thank you but i still could understand 
actually App folder inside the wwwroot folder so why i did not include the  App folder to path ?

Comment: I amended my answer with an explanation of why the path looks like it does.